# MMDetection ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (4,)

Tags: python, yolo

I use mmdetection train model yolov3 but I got an error.
[image error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a1J0.png)

```
# Build dataset
datasets = [build_dataset(cfg.data.train)]
# Build the detector
model = build_detector(cfg.model)
# Add an attribute for visualization convenience
model.CLASSES = datasets[0].CLASSES
# Create work_dir
mmcv.mkdir_or_exist(osp.abspath(cfg.work_dir))
train_detector(model, datasets, cfg, distributed=False, validate=True)
```

[Result from datasets[0].get_ann_info(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBpsD.png)

Comment: Looks like somehow the image has no bounding boxes. Maybe try printing the  key in results containing bounding boxes and check if its empty, also if its empty you might need to check why this image is not being ignored